# Get records with similar sounds

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find all duplicate names from contacts table whose name matches by sound. Eg : Rita or Reeta , Microsoft or Microsift , Mukherjee or Mukherji.

I have used below query :

```
SELECT contacts.id 
FROM contacts 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT first_name, last_name, count(*) AS rows 
    FROM contacts 
    WHERE deleted = 0 
    GROUP BY SOUNDEX(first_name), SOUNDEX(last_name) 
    HAVING count(rows) > 1
) AS p 
WHERE contacts.deleted = 0 
AND p.first_name SOUNDS LIKE contacts.first_name 
AND p.last_name SOUNDS LIKE contacts.last_name 
ORDER BY contacts.date_entered DESC
```

The above query gives right results but takes a lot of time when there are many records.

Comment: And it will. Your issue _can not_ be resolved in quick way because the thing "sounds similar" can not be resolved in quick way. Thus, `SOUNDEX` is slow and so is the entire query

Comment: Is there any other way apart from using SOUNDEX which runs faster.

Comment: To determine which strings "sounds similar"? No. But if you may simplify the term "sounds similar" - may be

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a better (native) approach than `SOUNDEX()`. The reason it's slow is because it's a function and thus needs to work over all the records to calculate the value and work from there. A way around this would be to store the results directly into the table. I have no experience with these functions in MySQL but according to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like) it seems that you can convert your `WHERE` clause into

```
[...] AND SOUNDEX(p.first_name) = SOUNDEX(contacts.first_name) [...]
```

Thus if you'd already have these values pre-computed (and indexed!) the search for a matching record should be radically faster!

That said I'm having a hard time figuring out your query. I don't think you need the `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` there and even then I'm confused on how you want to group/filter the contacts !?

Do you want something like this :

```
SELECT c1.id as contact_id, 
       c2.id as similar_id
  FROM contacts c1 
  JOIN contacts c2
    ON c2.id <> c1.id
   AND c2.deleted = 0
   AND SOUNDEX(c2.first_name) = SOUNDEX(c1.first_name)
   AND SOUNDEX(c2.last_name) = SOUNDEX(c1.last_name)
 WHERE c1.deleted = 0 
ORDER BY c1.date_entered DESC
```

Which you could then optmize as suggested above to

```
SELECT c1.id as contact_id, 
       c2.id as similar_id
  FROM contacts c1 
  JOIN contacts c2
    ON c2.id <> c1.id
   AND c2.deleted = 0
   AND c2.first_name_soundex = c1.first_name_soundex
   AND c2.last_name_soundex = c1.last_name_soundex
 WHERE c1.deleted = 0 
ORDER BY c1.date_entered DESC
```

where first_name_soundex holds the result of SOUNDEX(first_name) etc.
When indexing you might want to have a covering index over `deleted`, `first_name_soundex`, `last_name_soundex`. 
(AFAIK MySQL does not suppored filtered indexes yet, otherwise you could limit the index to `deleted = 0` only).

Answer (score 0):

SOUNDEX is (IMHO) of very limited utility. An extreme example...

```
SELECT SOUNDEX('cholmondley');
+------------------------+
| SOUNDEX('cholmondley') |
+------------------------+
| C4534                  |
+------------------------+

SELECT SOUNDEX('chumleigh');
+----------------------+
| SOUNDEX('chumleigh') |
+----------------------+
| C542                 |
+----------------------+
```